# PHP Soap how can I do?

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I have this web service

```
{
    "UserName":"testing_user",  
    "Password":"pxt_rws_nsg",  
    "mid":"76074",  
    "cid":"260",  
    "Amount":"10.00",  
    "TransactionType":"1",  
    "Track2":"",  
    "ZipCode":"32606",  
    "CVN":"",  
    "CardNumber":"4111111111111111",  
    "ExpDate":"0817",  
    "NameOnCard":"Test",  
    "reversalid":"1",  
    "AppKey":"a8dcdf14-11c6-4201-a95e-a0512818c98f",  
    "AppType":"11021",  
    "HostUserName":"",  
    "HostPassword":"",  
    "UserTransactionNumber":"635846721314374531"  
}
```

Somebody can show me how I need to make the PHP/SOAP code.

Comment: We can't help you without knowing SOAP endpoint URL or documentation.

Comment: You need to see the PHP SOAP tutorials if you are asking how can you make a SAOP service to process this above data. And convert your this json type data into XML. There are lots of tutorials that you can see and develop you web service. http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_soap.asp and see http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php